# A fair die is rolled twice. Let X1 and X2 denote the outcomes, and define random variable X to be the minimum of X1 and X2. What is Var(X)?

Tags: probability, statistics

This question asks 4 parts.  I can get them all except for the VAR.  And I think I tried literally every combo and don't have it right.  Here is where I'm at:

**Q1: How many possible values are there for X?**

A1: 6 (pretty easy, min can always be 1-6)

**Q2: What is the probability that X=1**

A2: 11/36 (This is the probability that at least one of the two rolls is a 1.)

**Q3: What is E(X)?**

Expected Probability is the Summation of the P(i) * i

for each number, find the combination of rolls that allow for your "i" to be the min.  for example.  A 5's possibilities are (5,5) - (5,6) and (6,5) - therefore 3 of 36 roll combinations would be valid for a 5 being lowest.

- 1 * 11/36 = 11/36
- 2 * 9/36 = 1/2
- 3 * 7/36 = 7/12
- 4 * 5/36 = 5/9
- 5 * 3/26 = 5/12
- 6 * 1/36 = 1/6

A3: (summation) = 91/36

So far so good :)

**Q4: Var(X)**

VAR = E(X-mu)^2

I've tried to compute this with the above E(X) in so man ways I'm spinning. Obviously, I'm close but I just can't get this.  Can someone point me in the right direction to calculate the Var(X)?

Comment: One way is $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-\mu^2$  You already know $\mu$ and it's easy to adapt your calculation of $E(X)$ to $E(X^2)$

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz.  One question.  Like the above calculation I had to take the outcome * the probability.  So in thise case to do E(X^2) do I do it like this?


1^2 * 11/36 + 2^2 * 1/2 + ...

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For variance you know the formula. So find the $X-\mu_X$ for each X where $\mu_X $ is the mean or E(X) = 91/36. You can have columns like this:
$X. |. f(X-\mu_X).   $
where f is the frequency of each X (eg.instead of adding 1 eleven times , you can multiply by 11)
So now find $E(X-\mu_X)^2$. Which is average. So simply add the entries in last column,square the number, and divide by $\sum f$ which is 36. You will get the answer

Comment: The third column has a typo: it should have $f$ instead of $f^2$.